# Continuing a WordPress PHP Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm currently trying to develop a custom Wordpress theme, and on my homepage I need to add a second content block. I am using a plugin to do this, which simply requires me to add the following where I want the content block to be.

```
<?php the_block('Latest Products')?>
```

However when I add this it seems to have no effect which I believe is due to the formatting of my php. I'm fairly new to php, so any help is greatly appreciated.

My code is as follows - I've cut out the best part of the HTML. I think it's something to do with that 'endforeach' tag?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if(have_posts()) :?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php
 global $post;
 $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=4&category=1');
 foreach($myposts as $post) :
 ?>                     
<div class="blogsnippet">
<div class="postdate">
    <span class="top"><?php the_time ('j')?></span><br/><span class="bottom"><?php the_time('M');?></span>
</div>
<div class="postexcerpt">
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<p><?php echo(get_the_excerpt());?></p>
</div>
</div>

<?php endforeach;?>             

<?php the_block('Latest Products')?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

EDIT

Okay, so apparently it needs to be put outside the loop, however it still won't work. Any ideas?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if(have_posts()) :?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php
 global $post;
 $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=4&category=1');
 foreach($myposts as $post) :
 ?>                     
<div class="blogsnippet">
<div class="postdate">
<span class="top"><?php the_time ('j')?></span><br/><span class="bottom"><?php     the_time('M');?></span>
</div>
<div class="postexcerpt">
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<p><?php echo(get_the_excerpt());?></p>
</div>
</div>

<?php endforeach;?>             
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php the_block('Latest Products')?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This mostly depends on what the plugin is actually doing because your code syntax is correct.

If you are using the [Multiple Content Blocks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-content-blocks/) plugin and are using the latest Wordpress version 3.5.1 then I believe the plugin may not be compatible. I'd check the version compatibility of the plugin to your Wordpress install as this could be your issue.

**EDIT:**

The plugin works by applying a filter to the function the_content() so that is why it only works by declaring the_block() before the_content() function is called.

A solution could be to capture the output the_block() and use print it out later, as an example:

```
<?php 
    ob_start();  
    the_block('Latest Products'); 
    $latest_products_contents = ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean();
?>
<!-- Further down.. -->
<?php echo $latest_products_contents; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan - there's not enough data to determine it's compatibility yet - one person says it works but that's all. For some reason, I just don't see the second editable region in the page editor whilst it is outside the loop. If  put it inside the loop, specifically above the section calling the latest 4 posts it appears and works fine, even within the loop, but obviously I need it below there. This leads me to think something is incorrect with that code, but I'm not experienced enough to be able to tell.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer that should resolve the problem. Your code is correct, it's just the plugin that requires the specific ordering.